# Need a marquee with loop text and stop on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marquee

i've also tried the following, but its not a looping marquee. Is it possible to loop or any other jquery is there with both loop & mouse over function?

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" align="middle" direction="left" scrollamount="4" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">Scrolling marquee</marquee
```

Comment: your question is unreadable...

Comment: Yes, you need to clone your marqee text as N times as the container width. After you're done, as soon as one child text element exits the parent you need to re-append it to the parent. So what have you tried?

Comment: using an obsolete (and highly annoying) html tag like `<marquee>` is discouraged - of course, if it's surrounded by glitter gifs ....

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>My Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<marquee behavior="scroll" align="middle" scrollamount="4" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
Scrolling marquee
</marquee>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [LOOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) attribute. Also check this [link](http://html.com/tags/marquee/)

```html
<marquee LOOP=3 behavior="scroll" align="middle" direction="left" scrollamount="4" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">Scrolling marquee</marquee>
```